# How to get the values of elements inside the <td> element of a gridview control using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I need some help for some issues that I want to tuckle some issues about using javascript. I was using gridview control to display all my comments that are saved from the database. What I want is when the user hovers the mouse on each comment it will highlight the background which already solved and want to show one of the div element right there with close button and get the text value of one label control inside the  element during mouseover event. After getting the text value of that label during onmouseover I want to display it in another div element and I want to get the text value of another label control which is located outside the gridview during onmouseover event as well. Here are the details below:

HTML Layout:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label> //I want to get the text value of this control

<div id="test"></div> //here I want to put the text value of the name label control after getting it during onmouseover

    <div id="Username" style =" margin-left :100px; width :1000px">

 <asp:GridView ID="gvParentGrid" runat="server" Width="395px"
AutoGenerateColumns="false"  GridLines="None" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="0px"
            BorderColor="White" DataKeyNames="ID" onrowcommand="gvParentGrid_RowCommand"
            onrowdatabound="gvParentGrid_RowDataBound" >

<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField >
<ItemTemplate>

 <tr >

     <td id ="comment" onmouseover="highlightBG(this, '#C0C0C0');highlightNext(this, 'black')" onmouseout="highlightBG(this, 'white');highlightClear()" class ="highlightab" style ="border-bottom :2px solid Blue;border-bottom-color :Gray; border-left :0px; border-left-color :White; border-right :0px; border-right-color :White; border-top :0px; border-top-color :White;background-color :White;border-bottom :2px solid Blue;border-bottom-color :Gray; border-left :0px; border-left-color :White; border-right :0px; border-right-color :White; border-top :0px; border-top-color :White;background-color :White; height :100px; width :395px; margin-bottom :5px">
          <div id ="Close" style="display :none" ><asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="X" style =" cursor:pointer; margin-left :365px; border:0px; background-color :White; color :blue; font-weight :bold; " /></div>
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" style="  margin-right :5px; background-image :url('Image/imagebackground.png');"  ImageAlign ="Left" Height ="60px" Width="60px" />
            <asp:Label ID ="ComID" runat ="server" style="display :none" Text =' <%#Eval("ID") %>' />
            <asp:Label ID="name" runat="server" style="font-weight :bolder; color :Blue; "  Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>' ></asp:Label> // I want to get this value diplay it in the div test
            <p id ="content" class="minimize" style =" border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; max-width :395px; min-height :5px; margin-top :5px; margin-bottom :5px; margin-left :65px; display :block; background-color: #CCCCFF;"> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Comments").ToString() %> </p>
           <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("ID") %>');" style ="margin-left :65px; margin-top :1px" >
             <input id="btndiv<%# Eval("ID") %>" type="button" value="Reply" style ="border:0px; background-color :White; color :blue; cursor :pointer " />
          </a>

     </td>

 </tr>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>

</asp:GridView>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function highlightBG(element, color) {

element.style.backgroundColor = color;
var getval = document.getElementById("commentor").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = getval;
document.getElementById("Close").style.display ="block";

}
```

Summary to tuckle some issues.

1. I need the Close div to show in every row of the gridview when hover because as of now using that code above would only show the Close div on the first row but if you move your mouse to another row the Close div row still remains showing on the first row which should supposed to transfer or show in another row when moving the mouse to another row.
2. I need to get the text value of the name label which is located inside the  element of the gridview and display it in div test during hover.
3. I need to get the text value of the Label4 which is located outside the gridview during onmouseover as well.

Thanks for any help...I hope somebody could be able to help me tuckle this 3 issues.

Comment: Where is the function "highlightNext" defined?

Comment: What do you want to do with "text value of the Label4"?

Comment: @KJPrice..thanks for this code,I didn't have multiple elements with same id. I applied all codes below and it is now showing the div Close on every row with the X button but there are still some glitches, first the test div is showing the text value of Button3 which is X instead of the name Label which located inside the <td> element.Second is I can't clear now the Close div in the second row and rest rows since I forgot to give you my highlightClear function. function highlightClear() {document.getElementById("Close").style.display ="none";document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "";}

Comment: That is the highlightClear() function which I stated in my comment.Can you please correct and modify my highlightClear() function for my onmouseout event so it will clear all the Close div after moving away the mouse because that code can only clear the first row.

Comment: Thanks timmack. If I understand what I am seeing (although I haven't run this in asp.net), there is going to be a div with id="Close" in every <td/>. So there does appear to be multiple divs with the same id, which is a big no-no.

Comment: Yeah, it is only clearing the first one because it is looking for something with an id of "Close", the first one it finds it applies the style you mentioned. document.getElementById always returns just one element. You need to use document.getElementsByClassName('Close'); after removing id="Close" and replacing it with class="Close".

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to study jQuery (http://jquery.com/) along with dom manipulation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). It will take a bit of time to, but will bring lots of value to your programming skills.

Comment: Thanks KJ Price, yeah finally got it I applied all the principles in your code and I resolve everything except getting the value of Label4. As per advice you said change this to <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label> then I changed it. But when I tried to get the value of Label4 and putting it into the div test it shows like this [ObjectHTMLSpanElement] instead of "Label" right.Why?

Comment: Please help me one last time around here is the code I tried to use when getting the Label4 text value and displaying it in the test div element.function highlightBG(element, color) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = color;
    var Close = element.children[0];
    Close.style.display = "block";
  
   var getval = document.getElementById("Label4");
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = getval;
}

Comment: Can you modify my code I left on the comment above pls.?

Comment: I'm sorry you forgot to mention how to get the value of the name label which is located also inside the td element of the gridview, it's not in you code can you please add.Thanks

Comment: Hey! I was out of country and just got back yesterday. Sorry I failed with getting back with you. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Man, this seems really complicated. I might need you to draw a picture. Lol. From what I gather:

First off, you should not have multiple elements with same id. Change (id="Close") to (class="Close").

jQuery would be awesome for this sort of dom querying.

1)

```
function highlightNext(){
var highlightNext = document.getElementsByClassName('highlightNext');
    for(var i = 0; i < highlightNext.length; i++){
        highlightNext[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

2)

```
function highlightBG(element, color) {

    element.style.backgroundColor = color;
    //Instead of querying for "Close"
    var Close = element.children[0];
    Close.style.display = "block";
    var getval = Close.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = getval;


}
```

3) 
Change the label to give a static id

```
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
```

Query the label with what you already know:

```
document.getElementById("Label4");
```